Mock @aws-sdk/client-ses using vitest and node.js
I tried to mock aws SES sendEmail and sendRawEmail function in my vitest unit test but it is showing error
 undefined is not a spy or a call to a spy!
my main code is emailService.ts
import { SES } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
import { populateTemplate } from "../utils/index.js";
import {
  EmailTemplateContentsInterface,
  emailTemplateContents,
} from "../emails/contents.js";

const ses = new SES({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

export const emailService = {
  sendEmail: async (
    templateContentName: EmailTemplateContentsInterface,
    emails: string[],
    data: { [key: string]: string | number },
    removeCtaButton: boolean = false,
    source: string = "support@embrk.com",
  ) => {
    if (
      !(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" || process.env.STAGING === "true")
    ) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      const params = {
        Source: emailTemplateContents[templateContentName]?.source || source,
        Destination: {
          ToAddresses: emails,
        },
        Message: {
          Subject: {
            Data: emailTemplateContents[templateContentName].subject,
          },
          Body: {
            Html: {
              Data: await populateTemplate({
                templateContentName,
                data,
                removeCtaButton,
              }),
            },
          },
        },
      };

      await ses.sendEmail(params);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },

  sendRawEmail: async (
    source: string = "support@embrk.com",
    emails: string[],
    rawBody: string,
  ) => {
    if (
      !(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" || process.env.STAGING === "true")
    ) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      await ses.sendRawEmail({
        Source: source,
        Destinations: emails,
        RawMessage: { Data: Buffer.from(rawBody) },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
};

my emailService.test.ts  is
 describe("sendRawEmail function", () => {
        const originalEnv = process.env;
        beforeEach(() => {
            vi.resetModules();
            process.env = { ...originalEnv };
            
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            process.env = originalEnv;
        });
it.only("should send a raw email successfully in production", async () => {
            process.env.NODE_ENV = "production";
            const mock = vi.mock("@aws-sdk/client-ses", () => {
                const mSES = {
                    sendRawEmail: vi.fn(),
                };
                return {
                    SES: vi.fn(() => mSES),
                };
            });
            await emailService.sendRawEmail(
                "support@example.com",
                ["test@example.com"],
                "Raw email body"
            );
            expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
});

i used aws sdk mock also sinon stubs
 it.only("should send a raw email successfully in production", async () => {
            process.env.NODE_ENV = "production";
            const sendRawEmailStub = sinon.stub(SES.prototype, "sendRawEmail");
            sendRawEmailStub.resolves({});
            await emailService.sendRawEmail(
                "support@example.com",
                ["test@example.com"],
                "Raw email body"
            );
            expect(sendRawEmailStub).toHaveBeenCalled();
            sendRawEmailStub.restore();
        });

but got this error
Cannot stub non-existent property sendRawEmail
also tried aws sdk client mock but did not work.
i also tried jest factory method.
I need assistance in properly mocking the AWS SES client's sendRawEmail and sendEmail method for testing.

It seems the type of SES (I would assume) is not the one you're expecting. Don't you need to use SESClient instead?
